# Retrieving html local storage from ios app

Tags: ios, html, ipad, local-storage, trigger.io

I have an app on the ipad that uses html5 local storage to collect information. 
When internet is available you can enter an email address that posts to an app that emails it as a csv. This whole process worked when testing.

The problem im having is that there is a javascript error when posting. I have deduced that some of the data is corrupt in someway.

When testing on another ipad. I have learned that the local storage is not overwritten when updating the app. But it would be great if i could get a backup of this data.

So my question is. How can I get this app off from the iPad onto a machine with the local storage access it. Failing that, is there anyway to see any local storage information on an ipad app, without changing the app.

Comment: Adding an answer to this question. It may be specific to trigger.io which i used to package up the app. But incase somebody else finds it.

Plug in the ipad and go into xcode. Drag the app into a folder and open. Im using textmate, it opened as a package. Inside this `AppData->Library->Application Spport->Forge->webkit` in there you will find your local storage file.